# jQuery - disable checkbox if value match to elements in an array

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, checkbox, onload

i'm trying to disable checkboxes on page load but on a condition that the checkbox values match records in my database.

i found [To disable the selective check box on page load jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624615/to-disable-the-selective-check-box-on-page-load-jquery) and http://jsfiddle.net/R27wq/1/. the only difference between his and my situation is the condition at which the checkbox is disabled. for his situation, if the value of the last column is equals to 1.0, the checkbox will be disabled.

i want to do the same except i want to make the checkbox disabled if its value match the records in my database.

below is my database:

[image: my db]

and below is a snippet of the code from my checkboxes:

```
<td>
   <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A26">
</td>
<td>
   <input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A25">
</td>
```

the checkboxes look like this on the webpage:
[image]

if the checkbox value match to the 'reserved' column, it should be disabled.

how do i implement the same concept for my situation? i was thinking maybe i could store the value from database in an array then from there, compare all the array elements to all the checkbox values? or is there a better way? can someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code in the JSFiddle, just add `$(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked','true');` and an array and a `map()` or `forEach()` to check it.

```js
$(function() {
  var reserved = ["A26", "A28"];
  var seats = document.getElementsByClassName('seats');
  for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
    reserved.map(function(v) {
      if (seats[i].value === v) {
        seats[i].setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        seats[i].setAttribute("checked", "true");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  left: 20px;
}
body {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A26"><p>A26</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A27"><p>A27</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A28"><p>A28</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="seats" name="selected[]" value="A29"><p>A29</p>
```

Comment: i suddenly have an issue. if i select other checkboxes which are not disabled, the previously disabled boxes, say A25 and A26, will suddenly become enabled. why is that so?

Comment: @the.mungk no idea. could you post some code that might be the problem?